# Program to find parity

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

I'm trying to count the number of bits that are set to 1 but the total always comes to 1 (or 0 if there's none)
What am I doing wrong?

```
typedef uint32_t uint;

uint hamm_parity(uint data)
{
    uint total = 0;
    uint i;

    for (i = 0; i < 32; i++)
    {
        if ((data & (1u << i)) == (1u << i))
            total++;
    }
    if (total % 2 == 0)
        return 0;
    else
        return 1;
}
```

I also tried with:

```
if ((data >> i) & 1u)
```

Also tried changing "1u" to 1 and to a variable

Comment: Would you mind to extend your code to a [example], please? Optimally with some calls showing expected and erroneous actual output?

Comment: Seems OK. Maybe, there is sth wrong with your function input, I mean `uint32_t data`.

Comment: I would code the loop like this so that there is no need to know the number of bits: `for (i = 1; i != 0; i <<= 1)`. The bit masking will also be simpler. `if ((data & i) != 0)`

Comment: Your code counts the number of bits set to 1 correctly, and it's saved to `total`. You haven't explained the reason for doing the `total % 2 == 0`. Why is this there?

Comment: @Miket25 Parity says whether the number of bits is even or odd. And obviously the return value is 0 for even parity and 1 for odd parity.

Answer (score 2):

Okay so I found my error, I wrote the code on here in a simpler way so you wouldn't need context, but by doing so, I hid my error.

Instead of using 32 for the loop i used a constant, but I used the wrong one.
Silly me...

Thanks anyway for the help!

Comment: If you haven't already, instead of using some magic number you could use `sizeof(data) * CHAR_BIT`.